# Hey, I'm a beginner and I have a question. I can't retrieve the mingw bin thing from msys2 in order to run c on my terminal in vs code. What to do?

Tags: c, mingw, msys2

So basically I was writing this c code on vs code and tried to run it on the terminal by writing make file but it showed error and told me that make is not recognised. Turns out I had to download the C extension on my vs code, which I did and then I had to get this mingw bin thing to my path. So I looked at the step by step instructions byvs code. I followed the installation process on the MSYS2 website. The UCRT64 environment launched (the thing that looks like a command prompt). I wrote pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc on it and it downloaded some stuff but it ultimately said "failed to retrieve file". What do I do?

Sorry if I didn't make a whole lot of sense, I just started to learn coding.

I thought that I had typed something wrong but that wasn't the case.

Comment: Please show the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your pacman mirrors

```
sudo pacman-mirrors -g
```

If that doesn't do the trick then maybe refreshing the package list and upgrading resolves it.

```
sudo pacman -Syu
```